# every map can be replaced by a weakly equivalent fibration

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

What is the meaning of the statement "every map can be replaced by a weakly equivalent fibration"?

Answer (score 7):

It means that given any $f:A \to B$ we can find a space $E_f$ containing $A$ that  is homotopy equivalent to $A$ and a fibration $p:E_f \to B$ such that $f = p \circ i$ where $i:A \to E_f$ is the inclusion.  See Hatcher p. 407 (http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) for more details.