# Does the singular homology functor preserve injectivity and surjectivity?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was wondering if the singular homology functor preserve injectivity and surjectivity? I've been trying to figure out a proof or counterexample for ages now and I just can't.

This came up when I was looking at the reduced homology $H_p(S^{n},S^{n-1})$. To calculate it, I have looked at the canonical injection $$\iota: S^{n-1} \longrightarrow S^{n}.$$ I'm viewing $S^{n-1}$ as the equator of  $S^n$, in this case does the functor preserve injectivity? That is, I want to say that $\iota_*$ is injective. Is this true? Thanksarinos

Comment: It's false, there is an injection $i : \mathbb S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$  but the induced map is of course not injective.
For the surjectivity, think to the quotient map $ q : [0,1] \to \mathbb S^1$ which glue 0 and 1 together.

Comment: Based on your comments below, I have to ask: what is $\iota_*$? Apparently it's not just $\iota_* : H_*(S^{n-1}) \to H_*(S^n)$?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what you mean by relative homology preserving injectivity and surjectivity, so consider instead the following general point.

No interesting homotopy-invariant functor on spaces can preserve injections or surjections. The reason is that every map is homotopy equivalent to an injection and also to a surjection! There are very nice explicit constructions accomplishing this called the [mapping cylinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cylinder) and [mapping cocylinder](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cocylinder) respectively.

In other words, "surjection" and "injection" aren't homotopy-theoretically meaningful concepts.

Comment: A [Q&A](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1098801/10014) related to your point.

Answer (score 1):

Your example already answers your question. $\iota_*: H_*(S^{n-1})\to H_*(S^n)$ is not injective. Also, $\pi: S^2\to\mathbb{RP}^2$ is surjective but the induced map on homology is not.

Comment: Why is it not injective?

Comment: $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})\cong\mathbb{Z}$ but $H_{n-1}(S^n)\cong 0$.

Comment: We're talking about the relative homology. sorry I didn't make that clear. English isn't my second language.